# How to draw human body in html5 svg and roate it in 360degree

Tags: html, svg, html5-canvas

I want to draw a human body using svg. I have basic svg knowledge and want to know more. I have tried all the tricks to make it.

Please provide full description. Presently i have drawn human figure in svg now i want to rotate the image in 360degree view.

Comment: Please add more detail.

Comment: Samarth, I'm interested in learning about this. Did you happen to figure this out or have any links? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not something you can do easily with SVG unfortunately.

I would suggest the following approach instead:

- Use for example the free<sup>*</sup> [Daz 3D](http://www.daz3d.com/) or [Poser 3D](http://poser.smithmicro.com/) (commercial) to create the human body as a 3D model (includes textures, bumps and so on).
- Export the 3D model as for example Wavefront OBJ or Collada and convert that to a JSON Geometry format.
- Use [three.js](http://threejs.org/) to import the converted model and render it to canvas (it can use both 2D and WebGL).

3D models are also vector based so you have the same benefits as with SVG vector-wise but your "drawing" (model) is much better organized for applying 3D operations to them such as rotation.

You should in any case reduce the poly-count to make it actually usable for most users which can give a low-res impression (also depending on the texture quality etc.).

If you are not familiar with the 3D terms I'm using here just google them - there are plentiful of resources out there for these things.

*Note: although the Daz 3D software is free itself you will in most cases have to purchase content.*